# How to test if Firebase is connected and working in a Flutter project

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am having problem with Firebase in my Flutter project, and I therefore want to test that it is working. I wanted to fetch some data from Firestore and noticed it wasn't getting anything, so I tried to test that it was working, but I was unsure of the best method to do so. Is there a method or something I can use to verify that it is connected to Firebase and Firestore?

I tried to make unittests with Firestore, but they fail.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Questions should include some code along with troubleshooting so we have an idea of what the issue is. Please take a moment and review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Did you set firebase configuration correctly?
And you can try to get data from firestore.
and you will need to print in console what you are getting from firestore.
This is easy.
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/overview
You can follow this link.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: Your answer is not clear. Please try to understand what the questioner is asking about. The question is about Firebase itself, not about its services. What if the questioner does not want to do anything with the Cloud Firestore service? What if the questioner is not using Cloud Firestore service in their project?

Comment: Your answer is not clear. Please try to understand what the questioner is asking about. The question is about Firebase itself, not about its services. What if the questioner does not want to do anything with the Cloud Firestore service? What if the questioner is not using Cloud Firestore service in their project?